# ¿Por qué me retorna falso si el valor lo toma del input?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando validar con expresiones regulares si el valor de un input es o no un formato de correo electrónico, este es mi html:

```
<div class="input-container">
            <input id='input' type="text" placeholder="Email address" required>
            <input id='boton' type="button" value="Request Access">
</div>
```

Y mi código JS:

```
const userEmail = document.getElementById('input').value;
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');
const RE = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;

function emailIsValid ( ) {

    console.log(RE.test(userEmail));


    console.log(RE.test('arturoperez@gmail.com'));
}


boton.addEventListener('click', emailIsValid);
```

Cuando mando a llamar el metodo con la constante userEmail (esta constante guarda el valor del input) como parámetro, esta retorna false, pero si mandó a llamar el test y pongo directo el string me regresa true.

Comment: ¿Has probado cambiando el `type="text"` a `type="email"`?

Comment: Sí, mismo resultado.

Comment: el botón te dispara el evento? has intentado colocarle solo un valor "Request" o " Access"? podría ser algo que puedes probar.

Comment: Tienes que asignar el valor de la variable `userEmail` dentro de la función `emailIsValid()`. Así como está el código la variable se asigna antes que se ingrese el correo y al evaluar retorna `false` porque está vacía.

Comment: Justo era eso, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

### Esta es la razón

> Importante leer los comentarios que se han puesto en el código.

Si nuestro punto de partida es éste, cito:

> ```js
> const userEmail = document.getElementById('input').value;
> const boton = document.getElementById('boton');
> const RE = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
>
> function emailIsValid() {
>
>    console.log(RE.test(userEmail));
>
>    console.log(RE.test('arturoperez@gmail.com'));
> }
>
> boton.addEventListener('click', emailIsValid);
> ```

Podemos observar que la función **`emailIsValid()`** no está obteniendo un valor actualizado del campo de correo electrónico y lo podemos demostrar en el siguiente fragmento. Solo tiene agregar algo de texto en el campo de correo:

```js
// ...

// Debería tomar un valor del campo de correo:
const userEmail = document.getElementById('input').value;
function emailIsValid() {
    console.log( userEmail );
}
boton.addEventListener('click', emailIsValid);
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
    <input id='input' type="text" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <input id='boton' type="button" value="Request Access">
</div>
```

Se observó que en la **Demo** anterior no se obtuvo ningún resultado. Por tanto, cuando lo pasas a evaluar en la expresión regular devolverá `false` .

### Algunos cambios

Podríamos pasar un selector como argumento de la función **emailIsValid( selector )**, quedando declarada así:

```js
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');
const RE = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;

const emailIsValid = ( selector ) => {
    // Ahora está dentro de la función. Esto permitirá obtener
    // un valor actualizado, de manera que, podrás evaluar
    // el correo electrónico mediante expresión regular:
    const userEmail = document.querySelector( selector ).value;

    // Observar resultados:
    console.log( RE.test( userEmail ) ); 
}

boton.addEventListener('click', () => emailIsValid( "#input" ), false);
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
    <input id='input' type="text" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <input id='boton' type="button" value="Request Access">
</div>
```

Sin embargo, sería ideal poder utilizar la función para poder evaluar una expresión de forma sencilla a través de una condicional.

**Es decir:**

```js
if (emailIsValid(selector)) {
    ...
}
```

Vayamos a la demostración:

```js
boton = document.getElementById("boton");

const emailIsValid = ( selector ) => {
    const email = document.querySelector( selector ).value,
        RE = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;

    // Devolverá un true o false según los valores obtenidos
    // del campo de correo electrónico:
    return RE.test( email );
}

boton.onclick = () => {
    // Evaluando si es un correo válido:
    if ( emailIsValid("#input") )
        console.log("Es un correo válido");

    // O si es un correo inválido:
    if ( ! emailIsValid("#input") )
        console.log( "Es inválido" );
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
    <input id='input' type="text" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <input id='boton' type="button" value="Request Access">
</div>
```

> **Importante:** si encuentra algo que no comprende acá o si necesita alguna mejora esta publicación me lo dejan en los comentarios.